# Get 64bit timestamps from a 32bit timer

Tags: android, c, timer, stm32

On my stm32wb55, I am using the 32bit-timer "tim2" for reading the time from 32bit-register "CNT" since system startup. With prescaling, I display the time in microseconds on my putty-console and it works very well. But now, I need to memory higher values. So I want to memory the time in a 64bit integer.

Does anyone know a simple way for doing that?

Comment: `tim2` has a resolution of 32bits, if you want to have a 64bit counter, then you should set up an interrupt on overflow `0xffffffff`, and then increment a 32bit variable. This way you get a 64bit resolution counter.

Comment: Unfortunately, I know nothing about interrupts. Is there a Solution with a few lines of code?

Comment: Or can you describe simple how I can do that with an interrupt, please?

Comment: Look at this guide https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/arm/stm32/timers/hal/

Comment: In the guide, you will find how to use timer interrupts and interrupt handlers. Set up your timer interrupt and in the interrupt handler just increment an `uint32_t` variable. To get the whole new 64bit resolution just do this. `(uint64_t)((var << 32) & current_timer_value)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tim2` timer is a 32bit resolution timer, you want a 64bit resolution. There are two ways to emulate a 64bit counter, to keep track of your uptime.

1. One would be incrementing a variable each time you reach the unit of time that you want to keep track of. But that would be extremely inefficient giving that the microcontroller would be doing a lot of constant context switching.
2. The second way would be to extend the timer with a 32bit variable. Then incrementing such variable on an overflow.

```
MSB                           LSB
+--------------+ +--------------+
|  32bit uint  | |  32bit timer |
+--------------+ +--------------+
```

The way this works is that after the timer reaches `0xffffffff` which is the maximum for a 32bit unsigned counter, the timer will overflow and start back at 0. If there was another bit after that 32'th bit, it will flip on(which is the same as incrementing). What you can do is emulate this exact behavior by incrementing a variable.

First, set up your timer.

```c
static TIM_HandleTypeDef s_TimerInstance = { 
    .Instance = TIM2
};

void setup_timer()
{
    __TIM2_CLK_ENABLE();
    s_TimerInstance.Init.Prescaler = ##; //Chose the correct value that fits your needs
    s_TimerInstance.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
    s_TimerInstance.Init.Period = 0xffffffff; //Chose the correct value that fits your needs
    s_TimerInstance.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1; //Also choose this value
    s_TimerInstance.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
    HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&s_TimerInstance);
    HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&s_TimerInstance);
}
```

Your handler, this has to be called each time your timer reaches `0xffffffff`

```
extern void TIM2_IRQHandler();
void TIM2_IRQHandler()
{
    HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&s_TimerInstance);
}

uint32_t extension;

void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
    extension++; //Increment
}
```

Combine the extension variable and the timer value. Use this function each time you want to get the extender counter value. You can make it inline to avoid extra calls, or as a macro.

```
uint64_t get_time()
{
    return (extension << 32) & (__HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&s_TimerInstance));
}
```

Now glue everything together

```
int main(void)
{
    HAL_Init(); //Initialize HAL library
    InitializeTimer(); //Initialize timer
    
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(TIM2_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM2_IRQn);

    while(1);
}
```

Note, that now tim2 will be used until it overflows. It should not be changed, or the following code will not work. Also, setup the divider, so the timer increment each microsecond as you stated earlier.

Also, you can use the timer to count seconds and then calculate the microsecond instead. If you count seconds instead you can count up to `2^32` seconds which is 4294967296. A year has about 31536000 seconds. With a 32bit counter `(4294967296/31536000)` you can count up to 136.19252 years of uptime. Then get the microseconds by dividing the uptime with 1000000 `(uptime/1000000)`. I don't know what are you planning to do with the microcontroller, but counting seconds sounds more sensical for me.

If you really want precision, you can still do it by counting seconds, you can add the timer counter value to the microsecond count, which you can get by diving the seconds down into microseconds, that way you offset microseconds that haven't been added to the second count.

Comment: Thank you very much so far! Unfortunately, I have a syntax errro by adding this method in my code:

`extern "C" void TIM2_IRQHandler()
{
    HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&s_TimerInstance);
}`

Are there any further actions needed to use this? I must say, I have never used a function from this type before...

Comment: In addition, I want to call the time counter value frequently in the while loop in main. But if I put the method `get_time()` in `while(1)`, I get the time directly with 64bits, even though my value is lower than `0xffffffff`, right?

Comment: Or is there a special place in the code where I have to put the method `extern "C" void TIM2_IRQHandler() {     HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&s_TimerInstance); }` ?

Comment: Oh my fault, you don't need the `extern "C"` giving that you are using C.

Comment: " if I put the method get_time() in while(1), I get the time directly with 64bits, even though my value is lower than 0xffffffff, right? " Yes, you will get a 64bit value.

Comment: I think get_time() has a race condition: If between reading extension and reading the counter from a register, it overflows, then the returned value would be wrong.
For example the following sequence might be generated: 0x0FFFFFFFF - 0x000000000 - 0x100000001.
Reading the extension before and after the counter, an overflow could be detected and the counter corrected.

Comment: @Meixner You are right. I think get_time() would need to be blocked by an atomic flag or a semaphore whenever the extension variable is being updated.

Comment: Using semaphores does not work, since that does not stop the timer from counting. Since the code updating the extension variable is running inside an IRQ, it is already kind of atomic for non-IRQ code.

Comment: @Meixner I think blocking get_time for the duration of HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback would solve the race condition. It does not stop the counter from counting but it does stop get_time from getting the incorrect value whenever the timer overflows.

Answer (score 2):

If you only access this from a non-ISR [non interrupt service] context, it's pretty simple.

If you have an ISR, the base level needs to lock/unlock interrupt handling. The ISR does *not* have to be related to the timer interrrupt. It could be for *any* ISR (e.g. tty, disk, SPI, video/audio, whatever).

Here's some representative code for a simple semi-baremetal implementation [this is similar to what I've done in some R/T commercial products, notably in a `microblaze` inside a Xilinx FPGA]:

```
typedef unsigned int u32;
typedef unsigned long long u64;

volatile int in_isr;                    // 1=inside an ISR

volatile u32 oldlo;                     // old LSW timer value
volatile u32 oldhi;                     // MSW of 64 bit timer

// clear and enable the CPU interrupt flag
void cli(void);
void sti(void);

// tmr32 -- get 32 bit timer/counter
u32 tmr32(void);

// tmrget -- get 64 bit timer value
u64
tmrget(void)
{
    u32 curlo;
    u32 curhi;
    u64 tmr64;

    // base level must prevent interrupts from occurring ...
    if (! in_isr)
        cli();

    // get the 32 bit counter/timer value
    curlo = tmr32();

    // get the upper 32 bits of the 64 bit counter/timer
    curhi = oldhi;

    // detect rollover
    if (curlo < oldlo)
        curhi += 1;

    oldhi = curhi;
    oldlo = curlo;

    // reenable interrupts
    if (! in_isr)
        sti();

    tmr64 = curhi;
    tmr64 <<= 32;
    tmr64 |= curlo;

    return tmr64;
}

// isr -- interrupt service routine
void
isr(void)
{

    // say we're in an ISR ...
    in_isr += 1;

    u64 tmr = tmrget();
    // do stuff ...

    // leaving the ISR ...
    in_isr -= 1;
}

// baselevel -- normal non-interrupt context
void
baselevel(void)
{

    while (1) {
        u64 tmr = tmrget();
        // do stuff ...
    }
}
```

This works fine if `tmrget` is called frequently enough that it catches *each* rollover of the 32 bit timer value.

Comment: why you do not use standard C types uint32_t, uint64_t  etc etc ?

Comment: @0___________ Because the linux kernel uses them. And, my original code used them. And, personally, I consider (e.g.) `u32` to be superior to `uint32_t` [gimme a break] because it's just and clear and _shorter_ [and it predates `uint32_t`]. Would `typedef uint32_t u32;` be more palatable?

Comment: it indeed saves a lot of ink