# Keil uVision5 armcc.exe: Problem with unsigned shorts in if statement not working correctly?

Tags: c, keil

armcc.exe V5.06 (750)
Please let me know why the code marked faulty does not work for as soon as the val16 overflows and becomes smaller than start_count. The loop no longer exits.

HAL_GetTick() return uint32_t (or int)

```
unsigned short start_count;

unsigned short val16;
unsigned short result;

start_count = HAL_GetTick(); 

//This does not work
do
{
    val16 = HAL_GetTick();
    result = val16 - start_count;
}
while ((val16 - start_count)  < 100);  //this part does not work correctly 
                                       //when val16 overflows

//This works!  same code logic
do
{
    val16 = HAL_GetTick();
    result = val16 - start_count;
}
while (result  < 100);
```

`

Comment: Why would you _want_ to do example #1 (which _doesn't_ work)? It's replicating the `val16 - start_count` calculation [and relying on the optimizer to fix that]. Example #2 is what I would have coded in the first place, so what's the issue? You mention that `HAL_GetTick` can return 32 bits [or 16 bits], so how would you/do you determine whether _your_ variables can be [merely] `unsigned short` or `uint32_t`. In any case, you have _unsigned_ quantities, and even with 32 bits, you have to handle potential rollover yourself. And, `newval - oldval` won't do that alone.

Comment: To handle rollover, see my recent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66124895/get-64bit-timestamps-from-a-32bit-timer/66125511#66125511

Comment: It is just a test to try understand this.
Rollover should not matter in unsigned arithmetic subtraction in this case and I have never had to manage it separately.

Comment: It doesn't if all you care about is the arithmetic. Or, short/delta intervals. But, you've got a 32 bit timer/counter that will rollover. If you needed a high precision absolute time, you _would_ have to care [per my link].

Answer (score 0):

First of all - do not use shorter types without special need as usually it adds additional overhead on 32 bits RISC targets.

The first while does not work because the arithmetic is done using ints not unsigned short values giving unexpected results :). Here you have a demonstration program:

```
unsigned HAL_GetTick(void)
{
    static unsigned tick = 65535 - 5;
    return tick++;
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned short val16;
    unsigned short result;
    unsigned short start_count;

    start_count = HAL_GetTick(); 

    //This does not work
    do
    {
        val16 = HAL_GetTick();
        result = val16 - start_count;
        printf("%d %d\n", (val16 - start_count)  < 100, (val16 - start_count));
    }
    while ((val16 - start_count)  < 100);  //this part does not work correctly 
                                        //when val16 overflows

    //This works!  same code logic
    do
    {
        val16 = HAL_GetTick();
        result = val16 - start_count;
    }
    while (result  < 100);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/fa5M7W

The second loop uses unsigned short types and it is not implicitly converted when result is calculated.

https://godbolt.org/z/6TshP8

Now the problem with not native integers using ARM Cortex cores.

Example program:

```
volatile uint32_t tick;

uint32_t HAL_GetTick(void)
{
    return tick;
}

void foo(void)
{
    unsigned short val16;
    unsigned short result;
    unsigned short start_count;

    start_count = HAL_GetTick(); 


    //This works!  same code logic
    do
    {
        val16 = HAL_GetTick();
        result = val16 - start_count;
    }
    while (result  < 100);
}

void bar(void)
{
    uint32_t val16;
    uint32_t result;
    uint32_t start_count;

    start_count = HAL_GetTick(); 


    //This works!  same code logic
    do
    {
        val16 = HAL_GetTick();
        result = val16 - start_count;
    }
    while (result  < 100);
}
```

and the resulting code:

```
foo:
        ldr     r1, .L9
        ldr     r2, [r1]
        lsl     r2, r2, #16
        lsr     r2, r2, #16
.L6:
        ldr     r3, [r1]
        sub     r3, r3, r2
        lsl     r3, r3, #16
        lsr     r3, r3, #16
        cmp     r3, #99
        bls     .L6
        bx      lr
.L9:
        .word   tick
bar:
        ldr     r2, .L15
        ldr     r1, [r2]
.L12:
        ldr     r3, [r2]
        sub     r3, r3, r1
        cmp     r3, #99
        bls     .L12
        bx      lr
.L15:
        .word   tick
```

As you see the version with 16 bits integers is less efficient than the one using 32bits native size integers.

Comment: Thank you. i am new t this processor and compiler. This is just a test because I stumbled across it yesterday and need to understand it. It will not be any final code.  I do not understand the answer. as I have also tried to cast everything back to unsigned short, even inside the arithmetic but it makes not difference.

Comment: This does not work either.
' while ((unsigned short)(val16 - start_count)  < (unsigned short) 100); '

Comment: it works. You need to learn C a bit better if you want to program uCs https://godbolt.org/z/davbT9